# Writing/pasting to a new value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to make a list of words I encounter frequently, adding onto the list if I haven't seen it before, and **add onto the Frequency Counter** each time I see that word again. The second half of this is what I need help with. I have two tabs, activeSheet and targetSheet. ActiveSheet contains the info I want to copy, and targetSheet contains the place I want to change the Frequency counter.

The frequency that gets pasted for a new word in the row is just 1. But if it's already in the list, I want the script to locate the previous input of that word and add +1 to the current value, before clearing the line.

At the moment, I'm simply using an index match to show the frequency value in the active Sheet, but the actual number is contained in my targetSheet.

TargetSheet also doesn't contain any formulas, it is just an A, B, and C column with content.

[Screenshot of activeSheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1ZpP.jpg)

My **activeSheet**: I've added a way to check if the word I want is already in the list, TRUE means it's already in there (and I would preferably add +1 to the counter, before clearing the input in this tab).

I am using the script below to find the original position of the word (Match formula in activeSheet to return the row number of targetSheet word) and offsets to paste it into the B column.

I'm not sure if it's possible to use formulas as values.getValue() in a script, and that's my problem?

**TLDR** Is there's a simpler way with Scripts to: locate the matching cell in targetSheet A column, and add +1 to the current value of the B column.

What I currently have for the -Add Frequency- button, it runs, but it doesn't change anything.

```
function addFrequency() {
  // Confirmation check
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var response = ui.alert("Move Row", "Move the selected row to the target sheet?", ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    if (response == ui.Button.YES) {

        // Start: Make the data

            // Get the current sheet object
            var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    
            // Add to the value
            var activeCell = activeSheet.getActiveCell();
            var OffsetCell = activeCell.offset(0, 1);

            var valueOfCell = OffsetCell.getValue() + 1;
            Logger.log("valueOfCell: " + valueOfCell);
    
            // Get the number of the row to move
            var rowToMove = activeSheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
            Logger.log("rowToMove: " + rowToMove);
        
        // End: Make the data

        // Start: Copy and paste the data
        
            // Get the target sheet
            var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("word list");
            
            // Get cell to paste to
            var frequencyRow = activeCell.offset(0, -2).getValue();
            Logger.log("frequencyRow: " + frequencyRow);
            
            // Get target to paste to
            var cellToPasteTo = targetSheet.getRange(frequencyRow, 2);
            
            // Copy and paste the data
            cellToPasteTo.setValue(valueOfCell);
        
        // End: Copy and paste the data

        // Pop up box tells you it's done
        ui.alert("Done. Rows moved.");

    }; // End: Confirmation check

}; // End: moveRows
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. About your image, I think that "壁" is included only one time in "目の前に立ちはだかる、高い高い壁。". But, in your expected value, 2 is used. Can I ask you about the detailed logic for obtaining your expected values? By the way, in your situation, you want to use the formula. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Edit your question to focus it on a single programming problem.

Comment: @Tanaike I added some arbitrary values to test the sheet.
It shouldn't be a problem (for my usage) because the frequency is a normal number value (that isn't changed by the sentence). The expected values for the function are just: if the word is already in the word list (TRUE) I want to add +1 to the value in the TargetSheet before clearing the row. 
If the word is not yet in the list (shown by FALSE value) I use the button 'add to list' to add it to the last empty row in the targetSheet with value 1, before clearing the row. This already works. Sorry for the unclear question.

Answer (score 0):

After redoing the code on a slightly less sleepy brain: this is what works for me. A whole lot simpler than my original mess of a code, for anyone who needs it.

```
function addFrequency() {
  // Confirmation check
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var response = ui.alert("Add frequency", "Add?", ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    if (response == ui.Button.YES) {

        // Start: In the activeSheet

            // Get the current sheet object
            var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    
            // Find the Active Cell
            var rowToMove = activeSheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
            Logger.log("rowToMove: " + rowToMove);
    
            // Get the range to move
            var rangeLocator = activeSheet.getRange(rowToMove, 1);
            var rowValue = rangeLocator.getValue();
            Logger.log("rowValue: " + rowValue);
        
        // End: In the activeSheet

        // Start: Copy and paste the data
        
            // Get the target sheet
            var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("word list");
            
            // Get range to paste to
            var rangePlace = targetSheet.getRange(rowValue +1, 2);
            
            // Add 1 to the frequency value
            var currentCount = rangePlace.getValue();
            Logger.log("valueToAddTo: " + currentCount);
            rangePlace.setValue(currentCount+1);
        
        // End: Copy and paste the data

        // Pop up box tells you it's done
        ui.alert("Done. Frequency Added.");

    }; // End: Confirmation check

}; // End: moveRows
```